# Call SQL stored procedure with named parameter in Groovy

Tags: sql, groovy

```
private static String XXX = "{call SP_XXX(?,?,?)}"
sql.call (XXX, [Sql.NUMERIC, Sql.NUMERIC,'SOME STRING'){
    outPara1, outPara2 ->
    log.info("${outPara1}, ${outPara2}")
}
```

I am able to call the stored procedure successful with the above code.

But, when I am using named parameters instead of '?' placeholder.
I am getting:

```
WARNING: Failed to execute: {call SP_XXX(:OUTP1, :OUTP2, :INP1)} 
because: Invalid column type
```

What I changed is replaced the '?' with ":OUTP1", "OUTP2" and ":INP1".
And in the call statement, using the named parameters accordingly.
The code after change:

```
private static String XXX = "{call SP_XXX(:OUTP1, :OUTP2, :INP1)}"
sql.call (XXX, [OUTP1: Sql.NUMERIC, OUTP2: Sql.NUMERIC, INP1: 'SOME STRING']){
    outPara1, outPara2 ->
    log.info("${outPara1}, ${outPara2}")
}
```

Comment: Was my answer useful in any way?

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is passing a `map` to `call()` which I do not think we have an api for. Moreover, the placeholders for the SP has to be `?`.

Either you can stick to your former approach or try using GString as below:

```
def inp1 = 'SOME STRING'
sql.call "{call SP_XXX(${Sql.NUMERIC}, ${Sql.NUMERIC}, $inp1)}", {
    outPara1, outPara2 ->
    log.info("${outPara1}, ${outPara2}")
}
```

I would prefer the former approach instead. :-)