# stored procedure named out parameter

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, groovy

Trying to use named parameters for calls to Oracle stored procedures.  The in parameters work fine but I can not seem to access the out parameters.

*Code for the test stored procedure is at the bottom of the page.*

```
/* imports and sql connection */
import groovy.util.GroovyTestCase
import groovy.sql.Sql
import lib.*
import java.sql.*
import oracle.jdbc.*

def sql;

this.class.classLoader.rootLoader.addURL(new URL("file:ojdbc7.jar"))
sql= Sql.newInstance ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@......", "..user..", "..password..")
```

The following example works fine using ? placeholders

```
/*** Example 1 ***/
/* Works fine using ? placeholders */

def greeting

println "**** Example 1 ****\n"

sql.call "{call groovy_test(?,?)}",
    [ 'Johny', Sql.VARCHAR ],
    { dbgreeting -> greeting = dbgreeting }

    println "greeting: " + greeting

/* Outputs: greeting: hello Johny /*
```

The next example fails with Invalid column type

```
/*** Example 2 ***/

def greeting2

println "\n**** Example 2 ****\n"

sql.call "{call groovy_test(:myname,:greeting)}",
    [ myname:'Johny', greeting:Sql.VARCHAR ],
    { dbgreeting -> greeting2 = dbgreeting }

    println "greeting: " + greeting    

/* Error
groovy.sql.Sql call
WARNING: Failed to execute: {call groovy_test(:myname,:greeting)} because: Invalid column type
Caught: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column type
*/
```

There is no output from the following example

```
/*** Exampl 3 ***/

def greeting3

println "\n**** Example 3 ****\n"

sql.execute "{call groovy_test(:myname,:greeting)}",
    [ myname:'Johny', greeting:Sql.VARCHAR ],
    { dbgreeting -> greeting3 = dbgreeting }

println "Test3 greeting: " + greeting3

/* Output: greeting: null */
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to access the out parameters when using named notation?
More complex procedures do run, and they do get the input values.  This has been verified in the table data.

Stored Procedure Code:

```
create procedure groovy_test( myname varchar2, greeting out varchar2 )
as
begin

  greeting := 'hello ' || myname;

end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a beginner with groovy so just throwing out ideas FWIW...

Just a hunch.. consider changing `Sql.VARCHAR` to a base datatype like String. Then you can always typecast the result to whatever type you desire.
You could also try Sql.LONGVARCHAR

Depending on version of Oracle varchar2 can be 4000 characters. May be Sql.VARCHAR doesn't handle that but Sql.LONGVARCHAR may handle it.

Also have you tried
     sql.execute "{call groovy_test(:myname,:greeting)}",
     [ 'Johny', Sql.VARCHAR ],
     { greeting -> greeting3 = greeting }

Finally, according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064834/call-sql-stored-procedure-with-named-parameter-in-groovy) the placeholders have to be ? only

Ref:
[Call SQL stored procedure with named parameter in Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064834/call-sql-stored-procedure-with-named-parameter-in-groovy)